# How does irqbalance determine which package to use?

Tags: linux, networking, performance

`irqbalance --debug` shows the following:

```
Package 0: Core 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14
Package 1: Core 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13
```

When I run network applications, it seems like IRQs are being handled by package 1, however the `smp_affinity` for the NIC is in package 0.

1. Does `irqbalance` override `smp_affinity` configuration?
2. How does `irqbalance` decide which package to use for handling IRQs?

Answer (score 3):

It's not a particularly big program, so just [checking the sources](https://code.google.com/p/irqbalance/source/browse) seemed like a good idea.

1. Does `irqbalance` override `smp_affinity` configuration?

   I believe the answer is no.
   If anything, you can clearly see it reading the `smp_affinity` setting out of
   the `/proc` filesystem in [`activate.c`](https://code.google.com/p/irqbalance/source/browse/activate.c#43):

   ```
   sprintf(buf, "/proc/irq/%i/smp_affinity", info->irq);
   file = fopen(buf, "r");
   if (!file)
           return 1;
   if (getline(&line, &size, file)==0) {
           free(line);
           fclose(file);
           return 1;
   }
   cpumask_parse_user(line, strlen(line), current_mask);
   ```
2. How does `irqbalance` decide which package to use for handling IRQs?

   This of course is the whole point of `irqbalance`, so what follows
   is likely to be an oversimplification.

   But from my reading, the relevant function is in [`placement.c`](https://code.google.com/p/irqbalance/source/browse/placement.c) in a function
   called `find_best_object_for_irq()`, which in turn calls `find_best_object()`.

   The critical line appears to be [here](https://code.google.com/p/irqbalance/source/browse/placement.c#122):

   ```
   asign = place.least_irqs ? place.least_irqs : place.best;
   ```

   Which would seem to indicate that the IRQ is assigned to that place
   (eg, package) that is currently has the fewest IRQs assigned; or
   if not, to the "best" place, where "best" is whatever has the 
   lowest load:

   ```
   newload = d->load;
   if (newload < best->best_cost) {
           best->best = d;
           best->best_cost = newload;
           best->least_irqs = NULL;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although, it does not answer my question as it does not address what is the relationship between smp_affinity and irqbalance Package configuration? It seems from your answer that "placement" actually doesnt care smp_affinity, rather it looks for cpu with least irqs, which can be CPUs outside the domain of smp_affinity. Infact irqbalance package configuration is different from smp_affinity, but as you pointed there seems to be some consideration for smp_affinity